# Why are axes flipped with a perspective camera?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to implement a simple perspective camera in Python with a right hand-coordinate system where +x-axis is right, +y-axis is up and +z-axis is out of the screen.

I have some code which projects points from 3D-world coordinates to 2D images coordinates. To test it I tried to project three unit vector along the +X, +Y and +Z axis and render them but when I do all the point appear to be "behind the camera", where as I would expect to see something like this:

[image]

When I uncomment the line `l = -l` the axis appear by all are flipped and when I rotate the camera around the origin pointing in they don't see to be rotating in the correct plane.

[image]

This is my code that shows the issue. Is there something I'm mis-understanding?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def compute_focal(angle, dimension):
    return dimension / 2.0 / np.tan( np.radians(angle) / .2)

# Positive camera at c looking at p with up=u http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/
def lookat(c, p, u):
    l = p - c
    l = l / np.linalg.norm(l)
    s = np.cross(l, u)
    s = s / np.linalg.norm(s)
    u = np.cross(s, l)

    # uncomment this and the axis will appear by are all flipped
    # l = -l

    R = np.vstack( (s, u, -l))
    Rc = R.T
    return Rc

# project 3D point into camera define by projection matrix
def projectPoint(P, point):
    xw, yw, zw = point
    W = np.array([ [xw, yw, zw, 1] ]).T
    xi, yi, zi = P.dot(W).flatten()

    if zi < 0.0:
        print("point {},{},{} is behind the camera!".format(xi, yi, zi))

    xi = int(xi + 0.5)
    yi = int(yi + 0.5)
    return xi, yi

theta = 0

while True:
    # used to rotate the camera around the y-axis looking at origin
    theta += 1

    w  = h  = 500
    fx = fy = compute_focal(w, 45.)
    cx = w / 2.
    cy = h / 2.

    K = np.array([ [fx, 0., cx], [0., fy, cy], [0., 0., 1.] ], dtype='float32')

    # position of the camera in world coordintes 1-unit from the origin rotating around the y-axis looking at the origin
    C = np.array([ np.sin(np.radians(theta)), 0, np.cos(np.radians(theta)) ])
    # pointing towards the origin
    P = np.array([ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ])
    # up direction is along the positive y-axis
    U = np.array([ 0, 1, 0 ])
    Rc = lookat(C, P, U)

    img = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype='uint8')

    # create the projection matrix from camera position
    R = Rc.T
    t = R.dot( -np.reshape(C, (3, 1)) )
    P = K.dot(np.hstack([R, t]))

    # draw and project positive principle axes
    x0, y0 = projectPoint(P, (0, 0, 0))
    x1, y1 = projectPoint(P, (1, 0, 0))
    x2, y2 = projectPoint(P, (0, 1, 0))
    x3, y3 = projectPoint(P, (0, 0, 1))

    # x-axis red
    cv2.line(img, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), [0, 0, 255], 1)
    # y-axis green
    cv2.line(img, (x0, y0), (x2, y2), [0, 255, 0], 1)
    # z-axis blue
    cv2.line(img, (x0, y0), (x3, y3), [255, 0, 0], 1)

    # flip image because opencv images have origin in top left
    img = np.flipud(img)

    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: is it because z axis is out of the screen? Because of that, openGL for example assumes the camera to look in -z direction, afaik

Comment: But isn't the right handed coordinate system?

Comment: right handed coord system is well, but this means the camera is watching "back", so visible objects have negative z coordinate in local camera system.

Comment: BUT: If you are using openCV functions for 3d reconstruction (and probably maybe projection) the coord system is different: x to the right, y to bottom, z to depth. That's because they want to keep the same y direction as for the image (origin = top-left, +y going downwards).

Comment: have a look at opencv cam model here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Comment: so, if you wrote your own projection code there could be 2 errors imho: 1. wrong z direction in front of the camera assumed (points behind the cam) 2. wrong y direction of the image assumed (upside-down result  because of image origin top-left instead of bottom-left)

Comment: Thanks I did find one error of not-normalizing the image coordinates from that document, but the axes flip still eludes me. I am flipping the image at the bottom of the code because of the OpenCV convention of top left being 0, 0

Comment: I just found this out figured I flipped a number somewhere. This flipped X axis wasn't the case a view years back (well the question is a view years old so must be slightly more). Some bug must have snug into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things seem to work correctly if I instead change the intrinsics matrix to:

```
 K = np.array([
            [fx, 0., -cx],
            [0., fy, -cy],
            [0., 0., -1.]
        ], dtype='float32')
```

With those entries negated. I'm not sure why but I saw in in some sample code and tried it and it works, although it's pretty unintuitive.